# Make array value unique

Tags: php, arrays

this is the dynamic array. I'm trying to remove the repeated value and have only merged one. e.g. need to remove `[0] => 1/2/48 & [1] => 1/2/48/56` and only have `[2] => 1/2/48/56/58` .

```
Array(
    [0] => 1/2/48
    [1] => 1/2/48/56
    [2] => 1/2/48/56/58
    [3] => 1/2/245
    [4] => 1/2/245/246
    [5] => 1/2/265
)
```

So the array should look like

```
Array(
    [0] => 1/2/48/56/58
    [1] => 1/2/245/246
    [2] => 1/2/265
)
```

Comment: Show us what you have tried first.

Comment: @linuxartisan I couldn't find a way to do it, thats why I'm asking here ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it

```php
$a = [
    '1/2/48',
    '1/2/48/56',
    '1/2/48/56/58',
    '1/2/245',
    '1/2/245/246',
    '1/2/265'
];

$result = array_values(
    array_filter($a, function ($value, $index) use ($a) {
        return !isset($a[$index + 1]) || 
               strpos($a[$index + 1], $value) !== 0;
    }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH)
);
```

*This assumes that your input array `$a` is sorted as you showed. Otherwise you'd need to sort it first.*

Answer (score 1):

if your php-version lt 5.6.0, and you haven't sort array like under

```
$a = [
    '1/2/245/246',
    '1/2/48',
    '1/2/48/56',
    '1/2/245',
    '1/2/265',
    '1/2/48/56/58'
];
```

you can try like this

```
$result = array_values(
        array_filter($a, function ($value) use ($a) {
            $is_exists = false;
            foreach ($a as $v){
                if (($v !== $value) && (strpos($v, $value) !== FALSE)){
                    $is_exists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            return !$is_exists;
        })
    );
```